# const int template does not seem to work inside a struct

Tags: c++, templates, struct

I am working with a code which needs a struct template which should contain a constant int variable like this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


template <typename T>
struct person {
  T age;
};



int main()
{
   struct person <const int> man;

   man.age=18;

   cout << man.age;
}
```

Unfortunately, the code above does not work.

It works when I set the instance template to int or char like this

```
struct person<int> man;
```

Or

```
struct person<char> man;
```

But not when I do this

```
struct person<const int> man;
```

Is there any other ways to do what I need to? Please point me out my mistake with proper explanation.

Comment: Please include the error that you are getting.  Being able to read those errors will likely be a key to solving issues like this

Comment: `age` is a `const int` in your broken scenario, so assigning `18` to it wont work. Thats the point of _const_. Try `struct person <const int> man{18};`

Comment: @Drew Dormann as the first question is answered , i am not including error message of the first one, but I have got another question update there you can see error message (2nd one).

Comment: @SubhaJeetSikdar if you have a new question, please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)!  Things get messy if you change this question after it has already been correctly answered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want `T` to be a `const int`, that means that `age` is `const` and can't be assigned to like you do with

```
man.age=18;
```

What you need to do is initialize `age` when you create `man` like

```
person<const int> man{18};
```

and now `age` is `18` and can't be changed.  Also notice that I removed `struct`.  Unlike C, in C++ you do not need to repeat `struct` to identify classes.

Comment: Thanks a lot,  friend, it works the way I wanted.

Comment: I have another problem, updated the code, can you please review?

Comment: @SubhaJeetSikdar Please ask a new question instead of editing this one.